# Why do I get complex eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvalue

I have defined a Hermitian matrix `H` which is a sum of Hermitian matrices `sigma_x`,`sigma_y` and `sigma_z`. When I compute the eigenvalues of this matrix, they turn out to be complex numbers (with a non zero imaginary part).

```py
import numpy as np
import math

sigma_x = np.array([[0,1],[1,0]])
sigma_y = np.array([[0, -1.0j],[1.0j, 0]])
sigma_z = np.array([[1,0],[0,-1]])

t = 2.82*10**(-19)
u=3**0.5
delta = 0.28*10**(-19)

H = u*t*(1*sigma_x + 1*sigma_y)*0.5 + 0.5*delta*sigma_z
eig_values, eig_vectors = np.linalg.eig(H)
eigvalue1=max(eig_values)                    
eigvalue2=min(eig_values) 
print(eigvalue2)
```

The output I get is `(-3.456616843099622e-19-4.870636306373122e-36j)`
The eigenvalues of Hermitian matrix must be real, why do I get complex eigenvalues?

Comment: The imaginary part is not strictly zero because of finite precision of float numbers on the computer. But it is so small, compared to the magnitude of your eigenvalue, that you can round it down to zero, manually.

Comment: you can also use `np.linalg.eigh` for computing the eigenvalues of a hermitian matrix with no imaginary component

Comment: That looks like (0, 0) to me.